# Qiskit - Quantum Neural Networks training

Tags: qiskit

Browsing through [these](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/blob/main/docs/tutorials/02_neural_network_classifier_and_regressor.ipynb) tutorials and noticing that there are no plots of how loss decreases with the number of epochs?

How could one do this with the `.fit` method [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.NeuralNetworkClassifier.html)?

How does one specify the number of epochs to train for too?

Answer (score 0):

Training of quantum neural networks and fitting corresponding algorithms is a slightly different story comparing to classical neural networks. These neural network based algorithms in Qiskit Machine Learning, like `NeuralNetworkClassifier`, `NeuralNetworkRegressor` and their subclasses, are hybrid quantum algorithms where a quantum circuit is actually a parameterized quantum circuit with a set parameters (weights). The goal of the training process is to optimize these parameters in way to minimize an objective function. So, this is an iterative process that is started by an optimizer, you may notice `NeuralNetworkClassifier` has a parameter `optimizer`.

Usually, an optimizer is a wrapper of one of the classical optimizers from Skikit-Learn. An objective function (cost function or loss in other words) passed to the optimizer is defined by a parameterized quantum circuit with a set of parameters as discussed above. An optimizer starts a loop, evaluates the objective function, optionally evaluates gradients, updates the circuit parameters, then evaluate the objective again and so on and so on. At the end, you get a set of values (weights) that minimizes the objective, thus yielding a quantum circuit (or QNN in other words) that produces desirable results.

Long story short - there are no epochs. An alternative to epochs is a `warm_start` parameter in the algorithms. It allows to re-use weights from the previous call to `fit` to start a new fit. But this is not a direct replacement.

Now, how can we trace loss during training? Well, in the current release 0.2.0 the only way is to pass a callback function to an optimizer, e.g. `GradientDescent` optimizer supports callbacks and has a corresponding parameter `callback`. When it is passed, you may get some insights how training is going on via calls of a user provided function. Another option is to build Qiskit Machine Learning from the sources. There's a recent feature introduced in this PR: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/pull/151. It enhances the algorithms and you may directly get a value of the objective function and an array of weights at each iteration.